# How can I store my `gets` method in a variable?

Tags: ruby, variables

I need to store a user input in a variable. This is my code:

```
puts "Hi! I'm HAL, what's your name?" 
gets.strip
name = gets.strip
greeting(name)
```

This isn't working.

Comment: Delete the second line. It reads from the input but discards the result. The answer to your question can be found in line 3.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you want, but it answers the question posed in the title.

You can hold the method [Kernel#gets](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) in a variable like so:

```
m = method(:gets)
  #=> #<Method: Object(Kernel)#gets>
```

Now let's use it.

```
def greeting(name)
  puts "Me? I'm #{name}"
end

puts "Hi! I'm HAL, what's your name?" 
name = m.call.strip # "Dave Bowman" is entered
```

`name` holds the user's response, after the string is stripped of any enclosing whitespace and the trailing newline character.

```
greeting(name)
Me? I'm Dave Bowman
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
puts "Hi! I'm HAL, what's your name?" 
name = gets.strip
greeting(name)
```